# Can I use other names for CC, CFLAGS in a makefile or they are hard wired into GNU make?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Can I use COMPILER instead of CC, or OBJ instead of OBJECTS? Will the `make` tool recognize them — is it just pure convention on my side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in rules use names such as `${CC}` (or `$(CC)` — the notations are equivalent). If you choose to use different macro names, you'll have to override/rewrite the rules to use your names:

```
%: %.c
    ${COMPILER} -o $@ ${OBJ} ...
```

If you're explicit, there won't be a problem:

```
hello: ${OBJS}
    ${COMPILER} -o $@ ${OBJS}
```

Note, though, that using the alternative names may make it harder for people to understand your makefile.  Makefiles can grow to be complex; one way of reducing their complexity is to follow the normal conventions.  I don't particularly recommend doing what you're suggesting, but it can be done.

Comment: Also, `CC` and `CFLAGS` are usually for C, and `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` for C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza: very true — I missed that detail.

Answer (score 1):

CC and CFLAGS are used by implicit rules but not OBJECT : (see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules)

OBJECT can be changed as it is not belonging to any explicit rule.

If you want to use other names for variables used in explicit rules, I think you have to define your own rules by adding something like that to your Makefile :

```
.cpp.o:
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILATIONFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands in default rules and names of variables used in them are [standardized by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html). GNU make to a certain extent obeys these. You're free to completely ignore anything built-in and use your own explicit rules and variables, though.